# How to prepare VPS enviroment for instalation and running of Ambrosus node?

Tags: parity, nodes, server-side

I would like to run Ambrosus development node. On Ambrosus github there are sume instructions, but I do not know how to prepare enviroment, what version of Ubuntu I should use and what tools should I install first?

https://github.com/ambrosus/ambrosus-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use what you want, parity and mongodb are in Docker,  but Ubuntu works great for me. You need to have Docker, and Node.js installed, maybe some others, you'll see with errors :)